# shopify order fulfillment issue using shopify_api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, shopify

I have a problem in fulfilling the line item in a order through shopify_api gem. When I fulfill a single line item it fulfills all the line items in the order. I have looked into it and people say something about setting headers, please clearify.

What I am doing is

```
order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(order_id)
```

Suppose this order has multiple line items

```
f = ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.new(:params => { :order_id => order.id, :line_items => [ {"id" => order.line_items.first.id} ] })

f.prefix_options = { :order_id => order.id }

f.save
```

This piece of code fulfills all the line items in the order and set the fulfillment status as fulfilled which was not desired.

---

Below are the details with header, fulfillment object and tcpdump:

Shopify headers

```
(rdb:1) p ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.headers
{"User-Agent"=>"ShopifyAPI/3.0.1 ActiveResource/3.1.1 Ruby/1.9.2", "X-Shopify-Access-Token"=>"be9d4adaa35e7f82b720a3567250424c"}
```

Fulfillment object

```
#<ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment:0xca2086c @attributes={"params"=>#<ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment::Params:0xca20b00 @attributes={"order_id"=>138494648, "notify_customer"=>true, "tracking_number"=>"12345678", "line_items"=>[#<ShopifyAPI::LineItem:0xca28904 @attributes={"id"=>225568082}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false>]}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=false>}, @prefix_options={:order_id=>138494648}, @persisted=false>
```

tcpdump output

10:07:14.498936 IP localhost.localdomain.34941 > localhost.localdomain.domain: 50737+ AAAA? olson-pfeffer-and-ratke1494.myshopify.com. (59)
E..W..@.@.D..........}.5.C.V.1...........olson-pfeffer-and-ratke1494    myshopify.com.....
10:07:14.655477 IP localhost.localdomain.domain > localhost.localdomain.34941: 50737 1/1/0 CNAME shops.shopify.com. (160)
E.....@.@.1.......X.   :....<
10:07:14.655650 IP localhost.localdomain.36871 > localhost.localdomain.domain: 39864+ A? olson-pfeffer-and-ratke1494.myshopify.com. (59)
E..W..@.@.D............5.C.V.............olson-pfeffer-and-ratke1494    myshopify.com.....
10:07:14.948404 IP localhost.localdomain.domain > localhost.localdomain.36871: 39864 5/4/4 CNAME shops.shopify.com., A 204.93.213.40, A 204.93.213.41, A 204.93.213.42, A 204.93.213.44 (301)
E..I..@.@.;..........5...5.H.............olson-pfeffer-and-ratke1494    myshopify.com..............X...shops.shopify.2.G.......X...].(.G.......X...].).G.......X...].*.G.......X...].,.M...........ns3.p19.dynect.net..M...........ns4...M...........ns1...M...........ns2..........0....NF.................0....NG.........0....
10:07:16.326985 IP6 geek-laptop.46193 > geek-laptop.46193: UDP, length 16
......@.................................q.q..j.............6k..
10:07:16.338153 IP6 geek-laptop.46193 > geek-laptop.46193: UDP, length 20
`......@.................................q.q../#........).....!.6k..
10:07:16.340185 IP6 geek-laptop.46193 > geek-laptop.46193: UDP, length 16`
......@.................................q.q...G..........!.6k..
10:07:16.350974 IP6 geek-laptop.46193 > geek-laptop.46193: UDP, length 924
`......@.................................q.q..tk........)...    ...............................................................................................".......".......f
......................................................................................................................................................................................................c
..................................................................................................2
..................................................................................................w
..................................................................................................)
..................................................................................................8

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is that when you're creating the fulfillment you're passing `:params => hash_of_fulfillment_data` to the `new` method. Just pass the data, you don't need a params key. This is just standard ActiveResource, nothing special. This should work:

```
f = ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.new(:order_id => order.id, :line_items =>[ {"id" => order.line_items.first.id} ] )
f.prefix_options = { :order_id => order.id }
f.save
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I am using shopify_api gem could you  please exactly tell me what headers need to be set? for eg. ShopifyAPI::Fulfillment.headers.merge!({:what => "here"})

Comment: Moreover I do not understand when they given the api and we are using the way it is along with the gem then why not gem taking care of setting headers correctly?

Comment: That's what the second part of my answer was about, it should be setting them correctly. That's why I was asking you to capture the actual request that is being sent and posting so that we can take a look at what is being sent.

Comment: I have provided the details below in the answer your question section as add comment does not allow me to post enough data. please check and let me know if anything can be done.

Comment: Santosh: thanks for the dump of info :) In the future, using a service like http://gist.github.com is your best bet as it lets you insert as much text as you want, and provides options for syntax highlighting, etc.